# Countable Field Extension of a Countable Field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Okay, first question on this site, apologies in advance for any mistakes I may make.

**Question:**
So I need to show that an algebraic field extension $E:F$, with $F$ being countable, is countable.

**My Thoughts:**
As far as I am aware, $E$ being algebraic means that every element in $E$ is algebraic (root of some polynomial in $F[x]$ ) and being countable means that there is a natural mapping of the integers onto $E$.

At the moment I am thinking that as every element in $E$ is algebraic then it has some corresponding polynomial in $F[x]$, that it is a root of, and then because $F$ is countable I need a bijection (or possibly just a surjection) of $F$ onto $E$ and that that may be achievable through the connection between an element of $E$ and it's polynomial in $F[x]$. I just can't see how to make this rigorous.

Note: I did try to find something resembling this question but mostly found analysis based questions. This may be down to my unfamiliarity with the website though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L/K$ be an algebraic extension. We have a natural map $\phi: L \rightarrow K[t]$ given by $\phi(\alpha)=\mathrm{min}_K(\alpha,t)$. Sadly this map need not be injective, for instance if $K=\mathbb Q$ and $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ then $\phi(\sqrt{2})=\phi(-\sqrt{2})$. So we have to work a bit harder. If $p(t) \in K[t]$ then hat can we say about the cardinality of $\phi^{-1}(p(t))$.

Now work in your original setting and recall that a countable union of finite sets is countable.

Edit: The argument concludes by noting that for each $p(t) \in K[t]$ we have that $|\phi^{-1}(p(t)) | \leq \deg p(t)$ so the fibers of $\phi$ are finite. In particular

$$L=\bigcup_{p(t) \in K[t]} \phi^{-1}(p(t))$$
so $L$ is a countable union of finite sets and thereby countable. This proof shows in general that any algebraic extension of an infinite field has the same cardinality as the base field.

Comment: Is your notation L/K the same as L:K? Also, I assume by the way you say it need not be injective that we do in fact need a bijective map for the countability?

Comment: @Nytram12 Yes $L/K$ means that $K \subset L$ is an extension of fields. Finding an explicition bijection to a countable set is one way to show countability but it's not the only way.

Comment: Oh? What other ways are there?

Comment: @Nytram12 Well countable sets are closed under countable unions and finite products for instance. So if you can write your field $E$ as a countable union of countable sets then you've shown its countable.

Comment: Fair enough. I suspect I am meant to go with the bijection route here. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nytram12 I've included the rest of the details of my argument. Did you have any luck finding an explicit bijection?

Comment: No I didn't but I followed what you suggested and wrote something of a similar nature to your edit. Thanks for your help :) No doubt there will be further Galois Theory questions from me in the near future :)